# BAT file is able to delete some files but not others

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a simple BAT file to delete some cached .sst files stored in app data.
I run the file but, my first line doesnt delete the .SST. I add a .txt file in the folder and modify the line to del .txt and it works. Thoughts? Or maybe a way to figure out a why? here is what I have-

```
@ Echo Off
del "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Entrust\ESPOLK\*.sst" /q /s> nul
del "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Entrust\ESP\*.sst" /q /s> nul
```

Thanks,
Mathew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `/f` switch to the command. E.g.

```
del "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Entrust\ESPOLK*.sst" /q /s /f> nul
```

This makes the command ignore most deletion constraints.

Comment: BOOM! Thanks. Now I just have to figure out how to wraper this and get out to everyone.